# Visual Studio 2017 UWP Apps crash

Tags: windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed Visual Studio 2017 Ent on Windows 10 (Creators update patch level)

After the installation UWP apps that I have developped no longer start. They crash with this error:

"Unable to activate Windows Store app. The xzy.exe process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start'"

[image: Application error]

Event creating a new project with a blank UWP application produces the same error.

The failure happens before the App.xaml.cs init is called.

Has anyone else ancountered this issue, and if so - how was ti resolved?

Edit: after further testing - it woudl appear that apps installed through Windows App Store work ok. Any side loaded apps fail.

Comment: Check if your directory has an `app.config` file...if you have it, delete it and rebuild the app.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - these's no app.config app anythere in the project nor in it's folder structure.

Comment: What configuration and platform are you using? Have you tried all four options: Debug, Release, x86, x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolevd the issue by reinstalling the Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx and Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx dependencies from the app packages folder. Hope this will save someone some time.

Comment: Detailed instruction: Open powershell. ``cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\Appx\Debug\x86``, run ``add-appxpackage .\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx``

Comment: I've got another system that was also missing the x64 Debug lib. Same fix with ``Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx``

Comment: your solution for me only work for x86 debug, now, the x64 debug does not return the error but also does not do nothing (the application does not start) do you know why?
(by the way thanks for the solution)