# Windows Universal Samples and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy

I had Visual Studio 2015 Community on my Windows 10 laptop. I removed that so that I could have enough space on my laptop for Visual Studio 2017 and the [Windows Universal Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). The project (specifically BluetoothLEClient) builds, but when I run it I get an unhandled exception and [image: error msg]. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459550/visual-studio-2017-uwp-apps-crash) thread, but I see the .appx files in their folders. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to refer [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404315/unable-to-activate-windows-store-app) that it solve it by deleting build directories.

Comment: The answer regarding TrueCrypt solved it for me.